# change variable with void method java

Tags: java, testes-de-unidade

boa queridos, estou precisando sua ajuda...
estou fazendo um curso, e um dos exercicios consiste em criar uma classe  com um metodo void(inicialmente)  que avance uma posicao na fila para un array, exemplo:
{1,2,3,4}-> after Cycle.swap({1,2,3,4})-> {4,1,2,3}

```
class CycleSwap {
static void cycleSwap(int[] array) {
    int[] replace= new int[array.length];
    for (int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(i==0){
            replace[i]=array[array.length-1];
        }else{
            replace[i]=array[i-1];
        }
    }
}
```

e o metodo que testa e o seguinte(teste q nao pode ser alterado e que nao esta pasando)

```
@Test
public void testCycleSwapSimpleCase() {
    int[] array = new int[]{1, 3, 2, 7, 4};
    CycleSwap.cycleSwap(array);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{4, 1, 3, 2, 7}, array);
    CycleSwap.cycleSwap(array);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{7, 4, 1, 3, 2}, array);
    CycleSwap.cycleSwap(array);
    assertArrayEquals(new int[]{2, 7, 4, 1, 3}, array);
}
```

o erro q retorna e o seguinte:
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: array contents differ at index [0], expected: <7> but was: <1>

desde ja agradeço cualquer ajuda :)

Answer (score 0):

O valor de `array` nunca é modificado, você está salvando os valores novos dentro de `replace`, então `array` nunca muda no seu teste.

Uma possível solução seria atribuir o valor de `replace` a `array` no final do `cycleSwap`.